# Need help GroupBoxes - and radio buttons I am very new to VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program that depending on which radio buttons someone clicks (only 1 button per `GroupBox`) and a total of 5 different group boxes. a specific value would be added To a num1Textbox Value that was entered.

The question is Can it be done? or am i wasting my time trying to learn it. I am very new to VB.. and have only done a cpl programs that add - mulitpy - divide and subtract values for the golf program for putting.. this time it will be more complicated I know.

Below is a pic of the program.

Someone would enter Yard to Hole = 145 (would be different number each time)

They would then select 1 radio button per `GroupBox` (5 different options) and the value 145 would increase or decrease accordingly depending which options is selected.

Sorry it would not allow me to uplaod a picture here :( so i uploaded it here.

sorry did not know you needed an account to view form there.. i will try to find a new place. 1 min

lets try here
http://i1311.photobucket.com/albums/s667/Steve_Lunney/design_zps9c2f89da.jpg

ANY help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you in advance

this is what i was trying.. as someones suggestion

but under each of these staements spinGroupBox.spin1RadioButton.Checked I get wavy lines and when i put my mouse over it it says - 'upRadioButton' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Groupbox"

```
Private Sub calculateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click
    Dim spinGroupBox As New GroupBox()
    Dim spin1RadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim spin2RadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim spin3RadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim spin4RadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim spin5RadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim num1TextBox As Integer
    Dim num2TextBox As Integer
    Dim spin1b As Decimal
    Dim resultA As Integer

    Select Case True
        Case spinGroupBox.spin1RadioButton.Checked
            spin1b = 0.095
        Case spinGroupBox.spin2RadioButton.Checked
            spin1b = 0.085
        Case spinGroupBox.spin3RadioButton.Checked
            spin1b = 0.08
            'etc
    End Select
    resultA = spin1b

    ' Create and initialize a GroupBox and a Button control. 
    Dim windGroupBox As GroupBox
    Dim upRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim ulRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim urRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim downRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim dlRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim drRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim leftRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim rightRadioButton As RadioButton
    Dim wind1b As Decimal
    Dim resultb As Integer
    Select Case True
        Case windGroupBox.upRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.095
        Case windGroupBox.ulRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.085
        Case windGroupBox.urRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.075
        Case windGroupBox.downRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.07
        Case windGroupBox.dlRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.065
        Case windGroupBox.drRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.06
        Case windGroupBox.leftRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.055
        Case windGroupBox.rightRadioButton.Checked
            wind1b = 0.05

    End Select
    resultb = wind1b
End Sub
```

Comment: ... so where's the picture? :)

Comment: This is not a very good functional specification.  Biggest problem with it that you plain forgot to ask a question.  That's required here.

Comment: If `upRadioButton` is not a child of `wind1b` then it is probably a direct child of the form. What are you using for the design? (...anything other than Visual Studio?)

Comment: the only thing i was trying to use is Visual Basic Express edition... i have never done any programming before and trying to self teach as i go

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it now, and as I posted in the comment, `upRadioButton` (and all the others) are (most probably) direct children of the form. That means you can write
`Case Me.upRadioButton.Checked`
(or you can leave out the `Me.`)
Btw., if you have pulled the controls onto the form in the designer, you should remove those `dim ...` lines. The controls are declared in another file that is hidden by default. Your lines declare variables again that shadow the access to the actual form controls, meaning that you get errors when you try to access them without `Me.`.